# ViewPager on activity with dialog theme

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-viewpager

I have an activity with a dialog theme (Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert)
Inside this activity i created a ViewPager because i want one image slider.
But my ViewPager create something like an actionBar before the slider. How can i remove it?

If my activity had an normal theme (not like a dialog) i could hide it doing the following code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

But it doesn't work in a dialog theme....

**EDIT**

My problem:
[image]

I want remove the "PageViewExample" =/

i already tried the following string and nothing happens

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: sure! image provided @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

I just added some style to my theme.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```